# Overloaded Method Value Sin With alternatives

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have been working on some Scala code for a homework assignment and encountered a strange error while working with the built in sin function that doesn't make a lot of sense to me.

```
val pi = 3.14159265
val REarth = 6371.0 // kilometers
def toRadians(x: Double): Double = x * pi / 180.0

def haversine(lat1: Double, lon1: Double, lat2: Double, lon2: Double): Double = {
    var lt1 = toRadians(lat1)
    var lt2 = toRadians(lat2)
    var dlat = toRadians(lat2 - lat1)
    var dlon = toRadians(lon2 - lon1)

    var x = sin(dlat/2)
    var a = x * x + cos(lt1) * cos(lt2) * sin(dlon/2)**2
    var c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1-a))
    return REarth * c
}

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
val haver = udf(haversine _)
```

When I run this code, I get the following error back:

```
<console>:37: error: overloaded method value sin with alternatives:
  (columnName: String)org.apache.spark.sql.Column <and>
  (e: org.apache.spark.sql.Column)org.apache.spark.sql.Column
 cannot be applied to (Double)
           var x = sin(dlat/2)
                   ^
```

I'm really not sure what is going on, as far as I can tell the sin function should work properly and I feel like I am missing something obvious. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you probabely have `sin`,`cos` etc imported from `org.apache.spark.sql.functions` (they take `Column`). If you want scalas math functions, write `import math._` inside `haversine`, or use `m̀ath.sin`, `math.cos`

Note also that `math` provides `toRadians` and also `Pi`, you don't need to define this yourself